# Inspect ngComponent in Chrome

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I've created an ngComponent with its own css, html and dart files.
The rendering works great, and the code runs correctly.

However, I usual style the dom elements by using Chrome's dev inspect tool and by dynamically modifying the css. I can't do this anymore with Darium and I don't seem to be able to get in the dom tree of the component. I'm always stuck with the component html tag.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In angular dart Ngcomponents are implemented using [Shadow DOM](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom/)

> Components isolate their views from their surroundings by creating a
>   shadow DOM. Using a shadow DOM allows components to be used anywhere
>   without suffering from things like CSS name collisions.

You have to enable show shadow DOM feature in dartium to see template of your custom component.

[image]

Comment: Awesome thanks! For those who don't know you access the settings page by clicking on the gear icon (top right) of the console.